# When printing out public and private key through console.log, I only get Unit8Array(32) returned

Tags: javascript

Learning how to create wallets on Solana. I am running node 16.14.0 and npm 8.3.1 on Windows 10 via bash command line and Visual Studios. Below is the code of my index.js file, but for some reason I am only getting  Uint8Array(32) output for the public key, but nothing returns for Uint8Array(64) for the private key to see if my test works. Am I missing libraries that should be installed?

```
const {
   Connection,
   PublicKey,
   clusterApiUrl,
   Keypair,
   LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
} = require("@solana/web3.js")

const wallet = new Keypair()

const publicKey = wallet._keypair.publicKey
const secretKey = wallet._keypair.secretKey

console.log(publicKey)
console.log(secretKey)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*nothing returns for Uint8Array(64)*"? Do you want to say that you only get the output from the first `console.log`, as if the second one didn't run?

Comment: Exactly this. It should out put both lines, but only the publicKey shows, even when I comment out the first console.log(publicKey) it still only shows the the publickey, nothing for privateKey.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I guess there was an issue with node 16.14.0 and/or npm 8.3.1, node 16.14.1 and npm 8.5.0 resolved it.